# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate cucumber runner class

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Here is my problem, I am converting existing cuucmber junit project to cucumber Testng project. Please find the runner class and console output.

Please let me know how do I resolve this .?

```
  package com.philips.rs.application.setup;
        import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
        import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
        import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
        import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;


    //@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            format   = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json","rerun:target/rerun_featureName.txt"},
            features = {"src/test/resources/com.philips.rs.testcases.browser.compatibility/"},                              
            strict = true,
            monochrome = true,
            glue = {"com.philips.rs.ui.stepdefs","com.philips.rs.backend.stepdefs","com.philips.rs.utils"},
            tags = {"@crossBrowser"}

            )
    public class PBPRunnerCrossBrowserUI_Test extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

    }
```

Please find console output, getting below error saying failed to instantiate runner class. I tried changing testng version in maven dependency , but no luck so far

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.8.2C:\Users\310242019\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1609683828\testng-customsuite.xml 
[BaseMessageSender] Waiting for Eclipse client on localhost:23856
[BaseMessageSender] Received a connection from Eclipse on localhost:23856
[BaseMessageSender] Connection established, starting reader thread
[BaseMessageSender] ReaderThread waiting for an admin message
[JsonMessageSender] Sending message [GenericMessage ==> suiteCount:1, testCount:1]
[BaseMessageSender] ReaderThread received admin message:>ACK
[BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK
[BaseMessageSender] Received ACK:>ACK
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.philips.rs.application.setup.PBPRunnerCrossBrowserUI_Test
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:27)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:63)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:561)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.<init>(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:27)
    at com.philips.rs.application.setup.PBPRunnerCrossBrowserUI_Test.<init>(PBPRunnerCrossBrowserUI_Test.java:19)
    ... 26 more
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.BaseMessageSender$ReaderThread.run(BaseMessageSender.java:267)
```

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between different versions of cucumber. Rather old ones at that. Can you include the dependencies from the `pom.xml` or `gradle.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the update, yes it was version mismatch , changes testng versions to 6.10 and updated cucumber-testng  to 1.2.5